# Order a list of dictionaries in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to sort this list of dictionary based on descending values of 'datetime' i.e starting from `1438887240` to `1438887255`. I need to store the result into another list of dictionary with this sorted result. I am new to python and trying a way to implement this criteria. Any help is highly appreciated.

```
res = [{'cpunumber': '40.0', 'servername': 'f02wn01', 'cpucore_sum': '5.0',   'cpucore_00': '0.399414', 'datetime': '1438887255'}, 
  {'cpunumber': '40.0', 'servername': 'f02wn01', 'cpucore_sum': '9.375', 'cpucore_00': '1.597656', 'datetime': '1438887250'}, 
  {'cpunumber': '40.0', 'servername': 'f02wn01', 'cpucore_sum': '3.195312', 'cpucore_00': '0.0', 'datetime': '1438887240'}, 
  {'cpunumber': '40.0', 'servername': 'f02wn01', 'cpucore_sum': '5.59375', 'cpucore_00': '1.0', 'datetime': '1438887245'}]
```

Comment: @mu無 Thanks a lot for your inputs! helped & learnt a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass in a custom `key` to the `sorted` function with `reverse=True` to get the descending order:

```
>>> res = [{'cpunumber': '40.0', 'servername': 'f02wn01', 'cpucore_sum': '5.0',   'cpucore_00': '0.399414', 'datetime': '1438887255'}, 
...   {'cpunumber': '40.0', 'servername': 'f02wn01', 'cpucore_sum': '9.375', 'cpucore_00': '1.597656', 'datetime': '1438887250'}, 
...   {'cpunumber': '40.0', 'servername': 'f02wn01', 'cpucore_sum': '3.195312', 'cpucore_00': '0.0', 'datetime': '1438887240'}, 
...   {'cpunumber': '40.0', 'servername': 'f02wn01', 'cpucore_sum': '5.59375', 'cpucore_00': '1.0', 'datetime': '1438887245'}]
>>> sorted(res, key=lambda x: x["datetime"], reverse=True)
[{'cpucore_00': '0.399414',
  'cpucore_sum': '5.0',
  'cpunumber': '40.0',
  'datetime': '1438887255',
  'servername': 'f02wn01'},
 {'cpucore_00': '1.597656',
  'cpucore_sum': '9.375',
  'cpunumber': '40.0',
  'datetime': '1438887250',
  'servername': 'f02wn01'},
 {'cpucore_00': '1.0',
  'cpucore_sum': '5.59375',
  'cpunumber': '40.0',
  'datetime': '1438887245',
  'servername': 'f02wn01'},
 {'cpucore_00': '0.0',
  'cpucore_sum': '3.195312',
  'cpunumber': '40.0',
  'datetime': '1438887240',
  'servername': 'f02wn01'}]
```

You can also sort it in place using the `.sort` method of the list (use `reverse=True` for descending order):

```
>>> res.sort(key=lambda x: x["datetime"])
>>> res
[{'cpucore_sum': '3.195312', 'cpucore_00': '0.0', 'servername': 'f02wn01', 'cpunumber': '40.0', 'datetime': '1438887240'}, {'cpucore_sum': '5.59375', 'cpucore_00': '1.0', 'servername': 'f02wn01', 'cpunumber': '40.0', 'datetime': '1438887245'}, {'cpucore_sum': '9.375', 'cpucore_00': '1.597656', 'servername': 'f02wn01', 'cpunumber': '40.0', 'datetime': '1438887250'}, {'cpucore_sum': '5.0', 'cpucore_00': '0.399414', 'servername': 'f02wn01', 'cpunumber': '40.0', 'datetime': '1438887255'}]
```

In case all your `dict`s are not guranteed to have the `"datetime"` key, you can use `x.get("datetime")` instead of `x["datetime"]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = [{'cpunumber': '40.0', 'servername': 'f02wn01', 'cpucore_sum': '5.0',        'cpucore_00': '0.399414', 'datetime': '1438887255'},
   {'cpunumber': '40.0', 'servername': 'f02wn01', 'cpucore_sum': '9.375',      'cpucore_00': '1.597656', 'datetime': '1438887250'},
   {'cpunumber': '40.0', 'servername': 'f02wn01', 'cpucore_sum':     '3.195312', 'cpucore_00': '0.0', 'datetime': '1438887240'},
  {'cpunumber': '40.0', 'servername': 'f02wn01', 'cpucore_sum': '5.59375', 'cpucore_00': '1.0', 'datetime': '1438887245'}]

y=sorted(x,key=lambda z:int(z.get("datetime")))
```

You can do it using `lambda` function as `key` to sorted.Also convert to `int` to make sure it is integer comparison rather than string comparison.

Comment: @suraj the answer you select will not give correct output.If you have values like `123` and `4` it will give `123` as smaller than `4` as it is `string comparison` and not `integer comparison`.